# Python max() vs min()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python code that works perfectly for getting the maximum summation from leaves to root node.
My goal is to change this to be the minimum summation instead of the maximum summation.
I thought I can just change the max() for min() function and it should record the minimum addition until it reaches the end, but it's not working for me.

I appreciate any feedback!

```
# This program will find the minimum cost of a binary tree

NodeMax = [0]*100
 
#Function for DepthFirstSearch traversal which stores the maximum value
#for every node until it reaches every leave
def DepthFirstSearch(values, vertex, unit, parent):
     
    #Initially NodeMax[unit] is always values[unit]
    NodeMax[unit] = values[unit - 1]
     
    #Maximum value from nodes
    maximum = 0
     
    # Traverse the tree
    for child in vertex[unit]:
         
        # continue if child is a parent 
        if child == parent:
            continue
         
        # DepthFirstSearch for further traversal
        DepthFirstSearch(values, vertex, child, unit)
         
        # keep the maximum of previous node and current node 
        maximum = max(maximum, NodeMax[child])
         
    # Add to the maximum value sent to the parent node
    NodeMax[unit] += maximum

# Function that returns the maximum value
def maximumValue(values, vertex):
    DepthFirstSearch(values, vertex, 1, 0)
    return NodeMax[1]
 
# Driver Code 
def main():     
    #amount of nodes 
    noNodes = 15
     
    # place all vertex in a list
    vertex = {}
    for i in range(noNodes + 1):
        vertex[i] = []

    values = [8, 4, 12, 2, 6, 10, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]

    # build the tree from the diagram with undirected edges
    vertex[1].append(2), vertex[2].append(1)
    vertex[1].append(3), vertex[3].append(1)
    vertex[2].append(4), vertex[4].append(2) 
    vertex[2].append(5), vertex[5].append(2) 
    vertex[3].append(6), vertex[6].append(3)
    vertex[3].append(7), vertex[7].append(3) 
    vertex[4].append(8), vertex[8].append(4) 
    vertex[4].append(9), vertex[9].append(4) 
    vertex[5].append(10), vertex[10].append(5) 
    vertex[5].append(11), vertex[11].append(5) 
    vertex[6].append(12), vertex[12].append(6) 
    vertex[6].append(13), vertex[13].append(6)
    vertex[7].append(14), vertex[14].append(7)
    vertex[7].append(15), vertex[15].append(7)

    print("the maximum cost of this binary tree is: " + str(maximumValue(values, vertex)))

main()
```

Comment: You should not initialize to 0.  Use the value in the root node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you forgot to change the initial value of `maximum` (now it should be `minimum`) to `inf`. And I've added the `if` statement because if it's a leaf, you shouldn't add `maximum` (`minimum`) because it's value in this case is `inf`, not `0`.

```
# This program will find the minimum cost of a binary tree


NodeMax = [0]*100

#Function for DepthFirstSearch traversal which stores the maximum value
#for every node until it reaches every leave
def DepthFirstSearch(values, vertex, unit, parent):
     
    #Initially NodeMax[unit] is always values[unit]
    NodeMax[unit] = values[unit - 1]
     
    #Maximum value from nodes
    maximum = float('inf')
     
    # Traverse the tree
    for child in vertex[unit]:
         
        # continue if child is a parent 
        if child == parent:
            continue
         
        # DepthFirstSearch for further traversal
        DepthFirstSearch(values, vertex, child, unit)
         
        # keep the maximum of previous node and current node 
        maximum = min(maximum, NodeMax[child])
         
    # Add to the maximum value sent to the parent node
    if len(vertex[unit]) != 1:
        NodeMax[unit] += maximum
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a binary tree using diagram, binary tree created with given array will follow this

> for any node at index i  has left child is at index 2i+1  and right
> child at index 2i+2

then you can use min and max with recursion

here is example to find min

```
def getMin(nodes, index):
    if(index >= len(nodes)):
        return 0;
    return nodes[index] + min(getMin(nodes, 2*index+1), getMin(nodes, 2*index+2))
    
nodes = [8, 4, 12, 2, 6, 10, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
print getMin(nodes, 0)
```